# Django forms - Allow a user to create a group for other users

Tags: django, django-models, django-views, django-forms

I am trying to let a user create a "club" (basically a group) where the user later on can add users to.

Currently it does not create a field in the database somehow.

Any suggestions would be appreciated since I am fairly new to forms.

**Model**

```
class Club(models.Model):
    owner = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    topic = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    start = models.DateTimeField(verbose_name='start date', auto_now_add=False)
    end = models.DateTimeField(verbose_name='end date', auto_now_add=False)
    account = models.ManyToManyField(Account)
```

**Views**

```
@login_required
def add_club(request):

    if request.method == "POST":

        form = AddClubForm(request.POST, instance=request.user)
        print(form)

        if form.is_valid():
            form.save()

        return HttpResponseRedirect(request.path_info)

    else:
        form = AddClubForm(instance=request.user)

    return render(request, 'page/club.html', {
        "form": form,
    })
```

**Form**

```
class AddClubForm(forms.Model):
    
    owner = forms.CharField(required=True)
    topic = forms.CharField(required=False)
    start = forms.DateField(required=False)
    end = forms.DateField(required=False)

    class Meta:
        model = Club
        fields = (
            'owner',
            'topic',
            'start',
            'end',
        )
```

**Template**

```
<form method="POST" action="">
    {% csrf_token %}
    <div class="col-md-6">
        <label class="labels">Create a club</label>
        {{ form.owner }}
        <input class="btn" type="submit" value="Add club">
    </div>
</form>
```

Comment: Hello, do you not have any error message? Why are you passing request.user as an instance to your form (it should be a Club instance)? In your template, any reason for `{{ form.owner }}` and not just `{{ form.}}` ? Also your Account M2M relationship is not `blank=True` so it expects it when creating the instance.

Comment: Hi Brise, No error messages. I pass a user as instance since I have to check if they are authenticated. In my template I use `{{ form.owner }}` since I will eventually add more fields, such as `form.topic` etc. Good point about `blank=True`, still nothing in the database though.

Comment: My bad for form.owner, did not see the other fields were marked as required=False. Needs `blank=True, null=True` in your model for these fields as well then. I still don't get the `instance=request.user` since instance needs to be a Club object, and your view already needs the user to be logged in via wrapper `@login_required`. Do you mean you want automatically the request.user to be set as the owner of the created Club ?

Comment: Solved it thanks to your `blank=True` and `null=True`. Thanks a lot for the input. When it comes to `instance=request.user`, you are right about that I could remove it. However, you can't pass a form as instance.

Comment: I posted the answer below. Do you mind validating it? Also i tried explaining that instance thing since it's quite an important feature of Django's ModelForms.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since this answered your problem, I am posting the solution here:

You need to add `blank=True, null=True` to your fields in your model, otherwise it expects them when saving the form.

```py
class Club(models.Model):
    owner = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    topic = models.CharField(max_length=30, blank=True, null=True)
    start = models.DateTimeField(verbose_name='start date', auto_now_add=False, blank=True, null=True)
    end = models.DateTimeField(verbose_name='end date', auto_now_add=False, blank=True, null=True)
    account = models.ManyToManyField(Account, blank=True)
```

Concerning the `instance=request.user`, I believe you misunderstanding the use of instance in a ModelForm.

If the request method is GET, the instance is used to **populate** a ModelForm with data from an existing Club object, and then pass it to your template to display the information.
If the request method is POST (or PUT), instance represent the existing Club object you want to **update** with data received from the form.

You usually need to use the instance arg in a DetailView (either to update or retrieve one specific Club), never when creating an object.

That's why you need to remove the instance arg in your views.py:

`form = AddClubForm(request.POST)`

Comment: That plus that I in my view I removed `instance=request.user` from `form = AddClubForm(request.POST, instance=request.user)`. Thanks for explaining, I think I will try to "play" around with it so that I understand it.

Comment: Yeah, gave the explanation but forgot to give the main point ^^. Thanks for reminding me, i edited my post.